# BuildFailedException: Incremental Player build failed!

Tags: unity, webgl

I'm trying to build simple project with only one shape
in WebGL, and I get these 4 errors.

I tried to install again and it's still not working.

```
Internal build system error. Backend exited with code 2.
STDOUT:
Finished compiling graph: 251 nodes, 786 flattened edges (786 ToBuild, 0 ToUse), maximum node priority 159
[  1/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/l6tb_System0.lump.cpp
[  2/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/as7o_System3.lump.cpp
[  3/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/as7o_System0.lump.cpp
[  4/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/osg1_System0.lump.cpp
[  5/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/j8vj_System0.lump.cpp
[  6/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/a90g_Mono0.lump.cpp
[  7/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/v9rq_codegen0.lump.cpp
[  8/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/ct68_gc0.lump.cpp
[  9/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/gkde_Generic2.lump.cpp
[ 10/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/7l1a_libil2cpp0.lump.cpp
[ 11/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/u0b2_System0.lump.cpp
[ 12/250    0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/_dummy_for_header_discovery
[ 13/250    0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/emscripten/yk06b/wrapper_emcc.bat
[ 14/250    0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/zlib/master_WebGL_wasm/_dummy_for_header_discovery
[ 15/250    0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/bdwgc/master_WebGL_wasm/_dummy_for_header_discovery
[ 16/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/as7o_System1.lump.cpp
[ 17/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/e37x_System0.lump.cpp
[ 18/250    0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/GameAssembly/master_WebGL_wasm/_dummy_for_header_discovery
[ 19/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/3tbv_vm6.lump.cpp
[ 20/250    0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/emscripten/jwr41/wrapper_emar.bat
[ 21/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/n6io_vm-utils0.lump.cpp
[ 22/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/3tbv_vm5.lump.cpp
[ 23/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/3tbv_vm4.lump.cpp
[ 24/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/3tbv_vm3.lump.cpp
[ 25/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/3tbv_vm2.lump.cpp
[ 26/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/3tbv_vm1.lump.cpp
[ 27/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/as7o_System2.lump.cpp
[ 28/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/3tbv_vm0.lump.cpp
[ 29/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/car2_Win322.lump.cpp
[ 30/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/gkde_Generic1.lump.cpp
[ 31/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/l3m8_System.Net0.lump.cpp
[ 32/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/j8vj_System2.lump.cpp
[ 33/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/j8vj_System1.lump.cpp
[ 34/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/pyvp_em.Runtime0.lump.cpp
[ 35/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/l8zo_System0.lump.cpp
[ 36/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/fefi_e.Remoting0.lump.cpp
[ 37/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/m2xi_System0.lump.cpp
[ 38/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/sep6_System0.lump.cpp
[ 39/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/x8gf_System.Net0.lump.cpp
[ 40/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/3zaj_metadata0.lump.cpp
[ 41/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/3zaj_metadata1.lump.cpp
[ 42/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/3zaj_metadata2.lump.cpp
[ 43/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/i8sg_ThreadPool0.lump.cpp
[ 44/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/s7y8_os0.lump.cpp
[ 45/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/s7y8_os1.lump.cpp
[ 46/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/4o2f_Android0.lump.cpp
[ 47/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/huo8_c-api0.lump.cpp
[ 48/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/huo8_c-api1.lump.cpp
[ 49/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/huo8_c-api2.lump.cpp
[ 50/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/huo8_c-api3.lump.cpp
[ 51/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/zqbw_tests0.lump.cpp
[ 52/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/zqbw_tests1.lump.cpp
[ 53/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/zqbw_tests2.lump.cpp
[ 54/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/zqbw_tests3.lump.cpp
[ 55/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/gyzq_m.Security0.lump.cpp
[ 56/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/91iw_LibraryPAL0.lump.cpp
[ 57/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/gkde_Generic0.lump.cpp
[ 58/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/i46q_Lumin0.lump.cpp
[ 59/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/hnam_OSX0.lump.cpp
[ 60/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/ke4u_Posix0.lump.cpp
[ 61/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/ke4u_Posix2.lump.cpp
[ 62/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/ke4u_Posix1.lump.cpp
[ 63/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/ke4u_Posix3.lump.cpp
[ 64/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/ke4u_Posix4.lump.cpp
[ 65/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/car2_Win320.lump.cpp
[ 66/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/car2_Win321.lump.cpp
[ 67/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/car2_Win323.lump.cpp
[ 68/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/b35q_WinRT0.lump.cpp
[ 69/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/car2_Win324.lump.cpp
[ 70/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/b35q_WinRT1.lump.cpp
[ 71/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/tljz_utils0.lump.cpp
[ 72/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/tljz_utils1.lump.cpp
[ 73/250    0s] MakeLump Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/tljz_utils2.lump.cpp
[BUSY       6s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/fin4_tils2.lump.o
[BUSY       6s] UnityLinker D:/projectsunity/My project (1)/Library/Bee/artifacts/unitylinker_ber2.traceevents
[ 74/250   13s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/mxb2_inRT1.lump.o
[ 75/250   16s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/czcm_tils1.lump.o
[ 76/250   18s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/fin4_tils2.lump.o
[ 77/250   21s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/tnlb_tils0.lump.o
[ 78/250   22s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/cv4n_in321.lump.o
[ 79/250   24s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/je1j_inRT0.lump.o
[ 80/250   27s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/yp6g_in323.lump.o
[ 81/250   23s] UnityLinker D:/projectsunity/My project (1)/Library/Bee/artifacts/unitylinker_ber2.traceevents
D:\unity\2021.3.21f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\build\deploy\UnityLinker.exe --search-directory=D:/projectsunity/My project (1)/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed --out=Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/ManagedStripped --include-link-xml=D:/projectsunity/My project (1)/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed\TypesInScenes.xml --include-directory=D:/projectsunity/My project (1)/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed --rule-set=Conservative --profiler-report --profiler-output-file=D:/projectsunity/My project (1)/Library/Bee/artifacts/unitylinker_ber2.traceevents --dotnetprofile=unityaot-linux --dotnetruntime=Il2Cpp --architecture=EmscriptenJavaScript --platform=WebGL --use-editor-options --enable-engine-module-stripping --engine-modules-asset-file=D:/unity/2021.3.21f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport/modules.asset --editor-data-file=D:/projectsunity/My project (1)/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/EditorToUnityLinkerData.json --print-command-line --enable-analytics
[ 82/250   29s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/18gz_in324.lump.o
[ 83/250    0s] WriteResponseFile Library/Bee/artifacts/rsp/5362588684057008505.rsp
[BUSY      18s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/cg1d_osix2.lump.o
[ 84/250   34s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/9bu5_in320.lump.o
[ 85/250    7s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/wxun_bit_stream.o
[ 86/250   35s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/ya36_osix4.lump.o
[BUSY      24s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/cg1d_osix2.lump.o
[ 87/250   41s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/fzbw_osix3.lump.o
[ 88/250   28s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/9wqv_osix1.lump.o
[ 89/250   28s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/cg1d_osix2.lump.o
[ 90/250   26s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/6vdl__OSX0.lump.o
[ 91/250   29s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/qlzk_osix0.lump.o
[ 92/250   28s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/vcsa_umin0.lump.o
[ 93/250   29s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/0u7c_eric0.lump.o
[ 94/250   29s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/k2af_yPAL0.lump.o
[ 95/250   28s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/60zl_rity0.lump.o
[ 96/250   24s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/yih6_ests3.lump.o
[ 97/250   26s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/f7pv_ests2.lump.o
[ 98/250   28s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/cofd_ests1.lump.o
[ 99/250   25s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/944u_ests0.lump.o
[100/250   28s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/zcld_-api3.lump.o
[101/250   28s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/g1t2_-api2.lump.o
[102/250   28s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/dijk_-api1.lump.o
[103/250   29s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/az81_-api0.lump.o
[104/250   28s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/q155_roid0.lump.o
[BUSY      29s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/ayqm_8_os1.lump.o
[105/250   29s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/ayqm_8_os1.lump.o
[106/250   29s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/7eg4_8_os0.lump.o
[107/250   30s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/fg0q_data2.lump.o
[108/250   33s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/pzf8_Pool0.lump.o
[109/250   33s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/w48f_data1.lump.o
[110/250   29s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/pq2u_.Net0.lump.o
[111/250   32s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/tlyx_data0.lump.o
[112/250   29s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/pkh2_stem0.lump.o
[113/250   28s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/rw8x_stem0.lump.o
[114/250   28s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/4xc9_ting0.lump.o
[115/250   29s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/oq36_stem0.lump.o
[116/250   32s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/hkhg_time0.lump.o
[117/250   29s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/ql2n_stem1.lump.o
[118/250   28s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/t4c6_stem2.lump.o
[119/250   29s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/a5jb_.Net0.lump.o
[120/250   28s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/j6yn_eric1.lump.o
[121/250   24s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/fef6_in322.lump.o
[BUSY      24s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/zob3_v_vm1.lump.o
[122/250    5s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/9htj_platform.o
[123/250   30s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/w50k_v_vm0.lump.o
[124/250    4s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/q8sw_fast_log.o
[125/250   34s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/5bwp_stem2.lump.o
[BUSY      35s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/zob3_v_vm1.lump.o
[126/250    6s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/ocdo_bit_cost.o
[127/250   35s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/27ll_v_vm2.lump.o
[128/250    6s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/zlib/master_WebGL_wasm/fes9_inftrees.o
[129/250   38s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/zob3_v_vm1.lump.o
[130/250   37s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/5qw3_v_vm3.lump.o
[131/250    5s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/zlib/master_WebGL_wasm/w42b_trees.o
[132/250   38s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/o2ne_v_vm4.lump.o
[133/250   34s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/rlyw_v_vm5.lump.o
[134/250    8s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/zlib/master_WebGL_wasm/rjrd_zutil.o
[135/250   34s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/71fs_tils0.lump.o
[136/250   33s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/6nwl_ThreadImpl.o
[137/250   10s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/zlib/master_WebGL_wasm/5pnn_gzlib.o
[138/250   35s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/fnjr_oryMapImpl.o
[139/250   14s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/bh4r_cluster.o
[140/250   12s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/zjdd_context.o
[141/250   35s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/jw6v_Evidence.o
[142/250   32s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/1lxr_UnityTls.o
[143/250   14s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/gw77_command.o
[144/250   16s] C_WebGL_wasm Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/il2cpp/master_WebGL_wasm/y6bf_huffman.o
[<message truncated>
BuildFailedException: Incremental Player build failed!
UnityEditor.Modules.BeeBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at <57a8ad0d1492436d8cfee9ba8e6618f8>:0)
UnityEditor.WebGL.WebGlBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/PlatformDependent/WebGL/Extensions/Unity.WebGL.extensions/BuildPostprocessor.cs:179)
UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <57a8ad0d1492436d8cfee9ba8e6618f8>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <57a8ad0d1492436d8cfee9ba8e6618f8>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 350 seconds (350158 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002da] in <57a8ad0d1492436d8cfee9ba8e6618f8>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <57a8ad0d1492436d8cfee9ba8e6618f8>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```